# Is there an official burn address on Solana?

Tags: nft

Is there an official public address where you can send tokens or NFTs to that are effectively burned and unrecoverable?

Comment: How can I burn my coin in solflare wallet

Answer (score 4):

Solana has a **burn** feature.

The Burn instruction decreases an Account's token balance without transferring to another Account, effectively removing the token from circulation permanently.

There is no other way to reduce supply on chain. This is similar to transferring to an account with unknown private key or destroying a private key. But the act of burning by using Burn instructions is more explicit and can be confirmed on chain by any parties.

You can burn easily by using phantom wallet which has recently supported this feature.

[source](https://spl.solana.com/token#burning)

Answer (score 1):

Suggest not burning your NFTs on Phantom as your are losing out on some SOL.

Use Metaplex’s full burn which will give you 0.008 SOL extra.

Links:

1. Metaboss burn - https://metaboss.rs/burn.html
2. Burn with metaplex sample code - https://github.com/loopcreativeandy/video-tutorial-resources/blob/main/nftBurn/nftBurner.ts
3. Sol Incinerator - https://www.sol-incinerator.com/#/